# Firebase Auth: Operation too fast

Tags: node.js, firebase, error-handling

I'm getting this error sporadically on my server's logs.

I don't even have steps to reproduce. Does anyone has had similar issues from normal querying?

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Operation too fast.
at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
at new FirebaseAuthError (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:149:16)
at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:188:16)
at /app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:1570:49
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Quota exceeded when updating users with Firebase Admin SDK - how can I request more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926113/quota-exceeded-when-updating-users-with-firebase-admin-sdk-how-can-i-request-m)

The actual code is `auth/quota-exceeded`